# Drupal: if I enable CSS files optimization my website layout changes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

So, this is funny.

If I Enable to Optimize CSS files, my website is stuck to the left of the browser window.

If I disable it, it is in the middle.

What's the reason of this behavior ? Are some CSS files badly merged or what ?

**Update**:

/* safari only */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
.list-add-to-cart {
    line-height:6px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like the merging isn't working correctly. Usually this is caused by bad CSS. I'd start by running it through the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that some files are cached and you get the wrong cached versions.

Clear the Drupal cache and your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: I've done it. Still it doesn't work. Clear All caches in drupal and my Firefox cache

Comment: I've just setup a VPS, I don't think there is a proxy at all